# How to intercept sub url request in nginx

Tags: nginx

I redirected all the URL request to  `upstream app` which is a Rails app.

But what if I want redirect a URL request `http://test-server/blog`  to another static website folder. Not related to Rails app.

How should I write my rule in `nginx.conf`

```
upstream app {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=60;
}


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  test-server;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `location` directive:

```
location /blog {
  # I suppose that the blog is inside another root directory
  root /path/to/blog;

  # Maybe you want some different logging policy
  access_log ....
  error_log ....

  # And so on... 
}
```